What is the meaning of the word Avatar?
I want to understand more about the word Avatar. What does it mean? Why and when did this word come into existence? share any references from the Vedas, Puranas or any other relevant books.

The word avatara means the one who appears or descends. अवतरति (avatarati) in Sanskrit is a kriyapadam (verb) which means to descend.
The word avatara doesn't seem to be directly present in the Vedas but the concept has been described.
It may be impossible to trace its origin as a large portion of the Vedas have been lost so we cannot rule out the possibility of the term being present in them.
The word avatara appears extensively in the Puranas such as the Bhagavata Purana.
Srila Krishnadas Kaviraj defines the word avatara in his work known as Sri Chaitanya Charitamrta.

sṛṣṭi-hetu yei mūrti prapañce avatare sei īśvara-mūrti ‘avatāra’ nāma
dhare māyātīta paravyome sabāra avasthāna viśve avatari’ dhare
‘avatāra’ nāma
sṛṣṭi-hetu — for the purpose of creation; yei mūrti — which form of the Lord; prapañce — in the material world; avatare — descends; sei — that; īśvara-mūrti — form of the Lord; avatāra — incarnation; nāma dhare — takes the name.
“The avatāra, or incarnation of Godhead, descends from the kingdom of
God for material manifestation. And the particular form of the
Personality of Godhead who so descends is called an incarnation, or
avatāra. Such incarnations are situated in the spiritual world, the
kingdom of God. When they descend to the material creation, they
assume the name avatāra.”

